# During training my loss curve has staircase shape. Why?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, loss, imagenet

During training of a CNN (RESNET50 on ImageNet) I'm observing a strange "staircase" shape (see the descending blue line in the plots linked below--sorry for the obscured legend text).

What might cause this? I use TensorFlow Datasets to get/generate the data, and the data is shuffled. I use batch size of 40 and 1000 batches (iterations) per "epoch", so each point on the plot represents 40,000 samples. The staircase steps down every 32 points, meaning each step spans 128,000 samples (much less than ImageNet's > 1,000,000 training images). I use the Adam optimizer with a fixed learning rate of 0.01.

Any guesses as to what may be causing this?

[Loss and accuracy curves, full view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgBj0.png)

[Loss curves, zoomed view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWC5v.png)

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: @AniketBote, I expect a "smoother" (but still noisy) descending curve, without the staircase/step shape. Are you implying that the staircase shape is common and expected? If so, why is it expected? I've been doing this for years and would only expect a staircase if the epoch sample size was equal to the full training set sample size, or if the learning rate decreased at intervals equivalent to the staircase step duration.

Comment: I could imagine it has to do with a combination  ADAM and your error surface shape since it scales the LR. Have you tried this with other / no optimizers?

Comment: @TA that's a plausible hypothesis. I'll see if it goes away when using standard SGD.